# How to modify xml-file to work with these queries?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have following xml-file:

```
<collection>
   <book author = "sp">
      <name>Birdguide</name>
      <pages></pages>
   </book>
</collection>
```

I want to return `<name>Birdguide</name>`

with these XPath queries: 
1. `//name[../preceding-sibling::*[contains(., "guides")]]`

2. `//name[realname(../..) = "assembled"]`

How do I change xml-file in order to get said xpath queries to work with xml-file shown above? For example `realname` is not part of xml-file yet because I dont understand where I need to put it in xml-file so that xpath query works.

Comment: Looks like [homeworks](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: XPath only selects nodes, it doesn't modify anything. For that you need either a complete XQuery or some other support in whatever client framework you're using. It's also not clear what the relationship is between the queries you give and the document, unless the document is incomplete, since there are no nodes with "guides" or "assembled" in the name.

Comment: @JeroenMostert you can use `xmlstarlet` to modify a XML file with xpath query

Comment: Relationship between queries and document is incomplete because I want to add them to xml-file in order to return said value with xpath. XPath queries dont need modifying, only xml.

Comment: The context is necessary because otherwise it's impossible to give a query that'll work properly. For example, `//name` will return the `name` node you're after just fine (along with every other element that happens to be called "name"), but I suspect that is in fact not what is needed here.

Comment: As mentioned above, your question is unclear; can you edit it with your exact expected output?

Comment: I edited it. The point is xml-file does not contain all parts of xpath query yet because those are the parts I need help with in order to get query working properly.

Comment: Then the question is really about making you understand what the queries mean, as you can't supply an XML document that meets the query's expectation otherwise. This is a neat way of asking you to demonstrate understanding of the queries, but it also means the question is not a practical programming question. Just giving a solution would not demonstrate why the queries work.

Comment: Can you explain how queries work then? I dont understand `name[.//` part and what `(../..)` means.

Comment: First query wants preceding sibling which contains word "guides" but adding element above name as sibling to name does not work.

Comment: `..` is the parent of the current node while `.` is the current node, so `../preceding-sibling::*` is not the nodes before the `name` node, but those before the `book` node. Likewise `../..` goes up two levels. Pay attention to where the axes end up and you should be able to figure out what nodes go where. (There are still many possible solutions with the only restriction that those two queries should work.)

Comment: Also, `realname`, as used here, is a function -- but not one that's part of the standard, so this may be a typo or a custom function that's defined elsewhere. (`local-name` would be an example of a function that is part of the standard.)

Comment: Would `local-name` work if I add `<collection> assembled </collection`? I dont want to add any functions, just simple elements or text so the xpath query works.

Answer (score 0):

One of the multiple solutions could be :

```
<collection>
    <book author = "sp">
        <assembled>
            <desc>
                <type>Type of guides</type>
            </desc>
            <details>
                <name>Birdguide</name>
            </details>
        </assembled>
    <pages></pages>
    </book>
</collection>
```

Works for the 2 following XPath :

```
//name[../preceding-sibling::*[contains(., "guides")]]
//name[name(../..) = "assembled"]
```

Output : `<name>Birdguide</name>`